# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-materialize'

Tags: reactjs, import, materialize

I'm trying to use a package called materialize, i installed it with `npm install react-materialize --save`, then I ran `npm install` but I get an error saying it can't find the package.

Failed to compile.

```
./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-materialize' in 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\reactcamera\src'
```

Package.Json

```
"react-materialize": "^2.0.6"
```

index.js

```
import {Button} from "react-materialize";
```

Comment: Have you done a npm install and npm run build if required?

Comment: Yes, doesn't have effect.

Comment: And can you see the package in your node_modules directory?

Comment: Yes it's in \node_modules\react-materialize\lib

Comment: Clearly mentioned in HTML Setup you need to add script https://react-materialize.github.io/#/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to include this in `index.html`:

```
<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>


<body>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

I don't understand why i have to include these in `index.html` but it works now.

Comment: Looking at the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-materialize), the first line `npm install materialize-css@next` is including the materialize-css as a node library. If you haven't done so, you could include the css manually as you did in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I tried 'yarn add --dev materialize-css' on terminal and it worked.

Comment: probably you should issue ''yarn add --dev react-materialize'' instead.